# What is the meaning of \x00 and \xff in Websockets?

Tags: formatting, message, websocket

Why do messages going through websockets always start with `\x00` and end with `\xff`, as in `\x00Your message\xff`?

Comment: I'm not sure, but most string systems out there are null terminated, an null is a \x00, could it be possible that you're seeing it the other way round? (ie: Your message\xff\x00)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [documentation](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-hixie-thewebsocketprotocol-76) might help...

Excerpt from section 1.2:-

```
   Data is sent in the form of UTF-8 text.  Each frame of data starts
   with a 0x00 byte and ends with a 0xFF byte, with the UTF-8 text in
   between.

   The WebSocket protocol uses this framing so that specifications that
   use the WebSocket protocol can expose such connections using an
   event-based mechanism instead of requiring users of those
   specifications to implement buffering and piecing together of
   messages manually.

   To close the connection cleanly, a frame consisting of just a 0xFF
   byte followed by a 0x00 byte is sent from one peer to ask that the
   other peer close the connection.

   The protocol is designed to support other frame types in future.
   Instead of the 0x00 and 0xFF bytes, other bytes might in future be
   defined.  Frames denoted by bytes that do not have the high bit set
   (0x00 to 0x7F) are treated as a stream of bytes terminated by 0xFF.
   Frames denoted by bytes that have the high bit set (0x80 to 0xFF)
   have a leading length indicator, which is encoded as a series of
   7-bit bytes stored in octets with the 8th bit being set for all but
   the last byte.  The remainder of the frame is then as much data as
   was specified.  (The closing handshake contains no data and therefore
   has a length byte of 0x00.)
```

Answer (score 4):

The working spec has changed and no longer uses 0x00 and 0xFF as start and end bytes

http://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-hybi-thewebsocketprotocol-04.html

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure about this but my guess would be to signify the start and end of the message. Since x00 is a single byte representation of 0 and xFF is a single byte representation of 255